# How to get unread mails from primary inbox in Gmail?

Tags: api, google-api, gmail, gmail-api, google-inbox

I'm using the Javascript client API with my app and I'm trying to get unread mails from the primary inbox.

If I use the INBOX and UNREAD names when requesting the labels I get all unread mails from all labels.

No other label type name works, I've experimented in APIs explorer and i can't seem to figure out how to manage this.

Am I missing something or is it not possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this "**in:inbox is:unread -category:(promotions OR social)**" as a value for q parameter in [messages](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list).list. I tried this in API explorer, and it gave correct results.

I have 4 "UNREAD" mails(or Threads) in my inbox, and response is:

200 OK

```
{
 "messages": [
  {
   "id": "14aea080215aa680", --- Thread 1
   "threadId": "14aea080215aa680"
 },
 {
  "id": "14ae8e25e92657e3", --- Thread 2
   "threadId": "14ae8e25e92657e3"
  },
 {
  "id": "14ae5e7a8bb1bc2f",-- Thread 3
  "threadId": "14ae433c5ae8de64"
 },
{
  "id": "14ae439fd8cd3726",-- Same thread 3 with different message id
  "threadId": "14ae433c5ae8de64"
 },
{
  "id": "14ae433c5ae8de64",-- Same thread 3 with different message id
  "threadId": "14ae433c5ae8de64"
 },
{
  "id": "14ae33d8431a06f3",-- Thread 4
  "threadId": "14ae33d8431a06f3"
}
],
  "resultSizeEstimate": 6
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try also this "in:inbox is:unread category:primary"

Answer (score 0):

You could try "in:unread category:primary "