# adding parameters to Gmail API

Tags: .net, vb.net, api, gmail-api

I was able to create a web based application for Gmail API to  get all the unread emails from specific email address in Javas Script. But I need to use stand alone application. I chose VB using VS 2017.
I was able to connect and Authenticated and get label but can't get to the part to search for unread (and from) using filter parameters.

```
scope.Add(GmailService.Scope.MailGoogleCom)
        Dim credential =GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(Secrets, scope, "Client ", CancellationToken.None).Result()
        initializer.HttpClientInitializer = credential
        initializer.ApplicationName = "Gmail API Quickstart"
        Dim service = New GmailService(initializer)
        Dim userId As String = "email@gmail.com"


Dim request As UsersResource.LabelsResource.ListRequest = service.Users.Labels.List("me")
        ' List labels.
        Dim labels As IList(Of Label) = request.Execute().Labels
        Console.WriteLine("Labels:")
        If labels IsNot Nothing AndAlso labels.Count > 0 Then
            For Each labelItem In labels
                MsgBox(labelItem.Name)
            Next
        Else
            Console.WriteLine("No labels found.")
        End If
```

I appropriate any help.
Thanks

Comment: Check this out - this might help, it is in C# but you could at least get the concept. http://www.developerfusion.com/article/4071/how-to-pop3-in-c/

Answer (score 0):

You may refer with this related SO post:  [How to get unread mails from primary inbox in Gmail?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27953600/how-to-get-unread-mails-from-primary-inbox-in-gmail). You can try this **"in:inbox is:unread -category:(promotions OR social)"** as a value for `q` parameter in [`messages.list`](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list). Also be noted that parameter cannot be used when accessing the api using the `gmail.metadata scope`.